# How to add X-header to unix mailx or add attachment to usr/sbin/sendmail

Tags: email, unix, sendmail, mailx

I am attempting to add the `x-header X-APP-VOLT: Yes` to the header of my email with a `.tar` attachment. I only have access to `usr/sbin/sendmail` and `mailx`. I do not have root access so I can't download other versions of `mailx` or `mutt`.

I can add the `x-header` to `usr/sbin/sendmail` using the below code, but I can't figure out how to add the `.tar` attachment.

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -- toemail << END
To: toemail
Subject: Test
X-APP-VOLT: Yes

Hope this works! END
```

I can attach a `.tar` file to `mailx` using the the below code, but I can't figure out how to add a `x-header`. My `mailx` also does not have the `-a` option.

```
cat file | uuencode filename | mailx -s "Test" toemail
```

Thank you

Comment: Same question cross-posted to serverfault: https://serverfault.com/q/701618/63769

Answer (score 0):

One way is to construct your input in a temporary file:

```
cat > tmpfile$$ << END
To: toemail
Subject: Test
X-APP-VOLT: Yes

Hope this works!

END

uuencode filename < file >> tmpfile$$

/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -- toemail < tmpfile$$
```

Also, I usually use sendmail's `-t` flag in this case, rather than repeating the recipient:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -t < tmpfile$$
```

If you don't want to use a temporary file, if you want to use a pure pipeline, you can use `( )` to create a subshell to do the construction:

```
(
echo "To: toemail"
echo "Subject: Test"
echo "X-APP-VOLT: Yes"
echo
echo "Hope this works!"
echo
uuencode filename < file
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -t
```

(Of course, these days most recipients will probably find it easier to deal with MIME attachments rather than uuencode.  It's pretty straightforward to create MIME attachments with a shell script, also.)

Comment: Thank you! I got the first method to work.  I haven't tried the pure pipeline method yet.

Comment: How exactly would you go about creating a MIME attachment instead of using uuencode?  I have only used uuencode before.

Comment: @sboat: First, see if you have the `mimencode` command.  That's what I use in my MIME-building script.

Comment: I don't have the mimencode command.  I checked for man mimencode and nothing was installed.

Comment: Sorry I actually do have mimencode.  Its setup as mmencode